# Duplicate class org.apache.commons

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, react-native

I am trying to run a build on Android. I'm in the process of building a React-Native bridge for a Java library. However, I am getting a `Duplicate class` error which looks like follows:

```
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.CompareToBuilder 
found in modules commons-lang3-3.9.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9) 
and creditCardNfcReader-1.0.3-runtime.jar (com.github.pro100svitlo:creditCardNfcReader:1.0.3)
```

There are an entire list of these errors being printed out. There is also a slightly different error which looks like this:

```
Duplicate class bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor found in 
modules bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0) 
and jetified-bolts-android-1.1.2.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2)
```

My dependencies currently look like this in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
implementation 'com.github.pro100svitlo:creditCardNfcReader:1.0.3'
    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

I have tried to exclude modules and groups from the dependencies with no luck yet. Here are a few approaches I have tried as recommended from several sources:

1.

```
implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:+") {
exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts', module: 'bolts-tasks'
}
```

2.

```
implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:+") { exclude module: 'bolts-tasks'}
```

3.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
implementation 'com.github.pro100svitlo:creditCardNfcReader:1.0.3'
    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

configurations { runtime.exclude group: '*' }
```

I would really appreciate any help with finding a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The exclude method of the configuration closure for a dependency excludes transitive dependencies. So, if your module dependency depends on other modules, you can exclude them from your build. You can check out the transitive dependencies of the 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+' module on its maven repo.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1

Try specify the version of dependency instead of use '+' to avoid conflict.

Here is some reference to check on resolving the plugins and dependency jar conflicts.

[jarjar package reference](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/blob/master/jarjar-gradle/example/build.gradle#L86)